# Opening Oracle SQL developer using VBA

Tags: vba, oracle-sqldeveloper, sendkeys

I am trying to open Oracle SQL Developer and connect to specific environment in my client machine using an Excel macro.

Problem is how long should the application wait before using SendKeys.
For instance I have used Wait for 1 min, and triggered sendkeys to Create new connection(CTRL N).
But SendKeys doesnt seems to be working. Any suggestion is appreciated.

[Sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUNKr.png) which i have used.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have accomplished the same by checking that the application has completed loading. You can do the same by doing something like this

```
 Sub IsTheProcessRunning()
        Debug.Print CheckProcessRunning("sqldeveloper64W.exe")
 End Sub

Function CheckProcessRunning(process As String)
    Dim objList As Object

    Set objList = GetObject("winmgmts:") _
        .ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='" & process & "'")

    If objList.Count > 0 Then
        IsProcessRunning = True
    Else
        IsProcessRunning = False
    End If
End Function
```

So in other words, you can use your code, but than open a loop with a timer and check at an specified interval to make sure that the application has completed loading and is ready to take commands.